# When is it better to use 64 bit File GDB access?

Tags: arcobjects, esri-geodatabase, api

The [beta 2 release](http://blogs.esri.com/Dev/blogs/geodatabase/archive/2011/02/09/File-Geodatabase-API-download-updated-_2D00_-Beta-2.aspx) File Geodatabase API includes 64 bit support.

Esri says arcobjects is still the "preferred" method to interact with the file gdb.  However, arcobjects has no 64 bit support.

Assuming licensing is not a factor, in what situations would it be better to use the 64 bit file gdb api rather than arcobjects?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's all about the memory limitations of 32-bit architectures. The benefit of 64-bit support is that you get access to 16 terabytes of virtual memory compared with 4 gigabytes in a 32-bit architecture. You also get access to more paging file space, system cache, etc.

It would be necessary to use the 64-bit version of the File Geodatabase API if you were reading a very large geodatabase into memory. That said, for general use the 32-bit version will likely be preferable even on 64-bit platforms.

Comment: Thanks Ray.  I suppose it should be possible to write a 64 bit implementation of a mapservice that complies with Esri's REST api that would out-perform ArcGIS Server mapservices, which are 32 bit.

Comment: I like the way you think, Kirk. ;)